# How do I convert a woff2 font to ttf using fonttools in Python?

Tags: python, fonts, truetype, woff2

I have woff2 files that I would like to convert to ttf using Python and the fonttools library. I have seen some methods on how to convert ttf fonts to woff2 but I can't use them to do the opposite.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out one can use `fontTools.ttLib.woff2.decompress()` to acheive this

Comment: I'm curious to know: what did it take to figure that out? Did you come across the right details on FT documentation? Piece together insights from posts on stackoverflow or elsewhere? Drill into the FT code?

Comment: I searched for info about "brotli" (a fonttools dependency required for woff2) and came across [this Github repo](https://github.com/google/brotli) which stated it was a compression format so I then tried to see what happens if I decompress the woff2 font using `fontTools.ttLib.woff2.decompress()` and I saw that it decompressed to ttf

Answer (score 2):

Here's the one-line command (on Windows):

`python -c "from fontTools.ttLib import woff2; import brotli; woff2.decompress('path/to/your.woff2', 'path/to/output.ttf')"`

Make sure you have installed brotli. Use forward slash (`/`) for the file path instead of backslash (`\`). The output can be either TTF or OTF.

Answer (score 1):

```
from fontTools.ttLib import woff2
# you also need brotli
import os

def convert(infilename, outfilename):
    with open(infilename , mode='rb') as infile:
        with open(outfilename, mode='wb') as outfile:
            woff2.decompress(infile, outfile)
```

Here's a CLI friendly script I wrote
https://github.com/basisvectors/woff2otf

```
python woff2otf.py (filename.woff or filename.woff2 or directory for batch conversion) [target file or dir name]
```